# Retag request: "whatsapp" to "whatsapp-messenger"

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

***WhatsApp Messenger*** is the real name of the app. Can [whatsapp](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp) be renamed [whatsapp-messenger](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp-messenger) (and "whatsapp" kept as a synonym)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems good to me; this is done.